# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::nameoffunction() Error with a page that worked before

Tags: php, authentication, usercake

I have problem with login page that worked well before. Error is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::signupTimeStamp()". My code derived from UserCake system of authentication.

```
<div id='main' style='display:none' >

Hey, $loggedInUser->displayname. This is an example secure page designed to demonstrate some of the basic features of UserCake. Just so you know, your title at the moment is $loggedInUser->title, and that can be changed in the admin panel.   You registered this account on " . date("M d, Y", $loggedInUser->signupTimeStamp()) . " .    usercode is: $loggedInUser->user_id.
</div>
```

dashboard.php

```
class loggedInUser {

    public $email = NULL;
    public $hash_pw = NULL;
    public $user_id = NULL;
    public $age= NULL;
    public $nome= NULL;
    public $dob= NULL;
    public $username = NULL;


    //Return the timestamp when the user registered
    public function signupTimeStamp()
    {
        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sign_up_stamp
                FROM ".$db_table_prefix."users
                WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($timestamp);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        return ($timestamp);
    }
```

class.user.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: where does the $loggedInUser variable come from?

Comment: //Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]))
{
 $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
}?> config.php